# React - dangerouslySetInnerHTML does not show correct result

Tags: html, reactjs

When I type below text on the textbox "Type Here"

```
AAA: 
<HEllo>

BBB:
<HE llo>
```

The Result should be same as the "Type Here".
The result box does not show the result which is same as the textbox, which share the same state.

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-cdn-z0wpu?file=/src/App.js:506-529

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply include linebreaks in your output container you could make use of the `<pre>` HTML tag. Change the following code in your example:

```js
  Result:
  <pre className="grey-bubble">
    {this.state.msg}
  </pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` doesn't escape HTML tags, which means they are rendered into DOM, and therefore don't appear as text. If you type `<strong>Hello</strong>` into your textbox, you'll see the bold "Hello" output. This is the correct behaviour of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Comment: Without changing the rest of the code, I'd escape the html tags from the original string and only then replace newlines with `<br />` tag. Example approach:
`__html: this.state.msg.replace('<', '&lt;').replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "<br />")`